# AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing applications for kafka-spark-cassandra interaction, and I can't get rid of this error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka.` When I worked with spark-streaming, this error did not occur and the application was launched from the ide. I tried to do as it is written in the guide [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) and run spark through the shell with the command: `./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1 ...`And now there is an error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\... (Access denied)'`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your Spark folder owned by a different user? What happens if you start a cmd as administrator and run that command?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, no, same mistake. I installed Spark according to this [guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10). And if I try to run `spark-shell` without administrator mode, this error will appear: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\uncle\.scala_history (Access denied)` Kafka and cassandra work fine without administrator mode. Spark shell should only run in administrator mode?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the folder belongs to me

Comment: Unclear why you did not follow the official Spark installation, but that link uses Spark 2.4, so maybe something changed. Personally, I don't develop on Windows, but you likely have to use `winutils` to run `chmod` or `chown -R` on each directory that says permission denied